# Can I treat my fish to too much food?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I never had any luck with pets when I was a kid. My parakeets died after a week. My bunny died after two days. My goldfish died within 6 hours. I was told I overfed the poor things.  I never had any pets after them again. Probably for the best, at that rate.

Then comes Mass Effect and the aquarium. Poor fish have no idea what's coming.

Every time I go into my room, I smack the feed button, just to be safe. But am I being too safe? Is it possible to overfeed these digital fish?

I don't even want to think about what happened to my poor [Tamagotchi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamagotchi)...

Comment: Why don't you just get the aquarium VI so you never have to worry about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want the fish to live, I would suggest you buy the Acquarium VI at the Presidium Commons on Citadel for 25k credits. I've never heard of overfeeding causing the fish to die, but the consensus is that the way to go is feeding them after every mission you complete.

Answer (score 1):

According to some vague sources, fishes can be overfed. But to be honest, if you ignore the fish, they die. If you feed the fish, they die. If you have Kelly feed the fish, they die (That's in Mass Effect 2). Bioware just created the fishes to troll the players IMHO.

It seems that your misfortune with pets is a common problem in Mass Effect. I know few (read: no) people that raised their fishes to be healthy and happy.

In addition, a tip to keep them alive as long as possible: It seems that fishes survive longest if you feed them after every assignment or mission you complete.

Comment: I haven't had a problem with keeping my fish alive.  Not sure about happy, but they were alive.  Well except this one time, but I learned from that.